# How can I adapt size of table with tabular environment in my document

Tags: tables, tcolorbox

I would like to insert data table in my document, for that I used the tabular environment, but I my case I have many columns to insert when I compile my tex document the table flows out of the border, can someone help me to resize this table to be inside of my document.

```
  \documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=3cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
 \usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,title= Statistiques ,attach boxed title to top center=
    {yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=purple } ]
 \section*{I- Vocabulaires}
\section*{II- Tableaux des effectifs et des effectifs cumulés de fréquences et de fréquences cumulées}
 \subsection*{Exercice d'application: }
 Voici les notes obtenues à une évaluation en mathématiques des élèves de$3^{\textrm{ème}}$:
 \begin{eqnarray}\nonumber\textcolor{violet}{10}  ;; \textcolor{green}{8}  ;;  \textcolor{purple}{9}  ;;  \textcolor{pink}{15}  ;;  \textcolor{cyan}{13}  ;;  \textcolor{brown}{14}  ;;  \textcolor{magenta}{12}  ;; \textcolor{red}{7}  ;; \textcolor{blue}{6} ;;  \textcolor{brown}{14}  ;;  \textcolor{orange}{16}  ;; \textcolor{brown}{14}  ;;  \textcolor{magenta}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{violet}{10}  ;;  \textcolor{purple}{9}  ;; \textcolor{green}{8}  ;; \textcolor{red}{7}  ;;  \textcolor{blue}{6}  ;;  \textcolor{purple}{9}  ;;  \textcolor{cyan}{13}  \\\nonumber  \textcolor{green}{8}  ;;  \textcolor{red}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{orange}{16}  ;; \textcolor{magenta}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{magenta}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{violet}{10}  ;;  \textcolor{violet}{10}  ;;  \textcolor{red}{7}  ;;  \textcolor{magenta}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{blue}{6}  ;;  \textcolor{red}{7}  ;;  \textcolor{green}{8}  ;;  \textcolor{purple}{9}  ;;  \textcolor{red}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{cyan}{13}  ;;  \textcolor{pink}{15}  ;;  \textcolor{blue}{6} ;; \textcolor{cyan}{13}  ;;  \textcolor{brown}{14}  ;;  \textcolor{brown}{14}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{itemize}
 \item Quelle est la population statistique\\la population statistique est les élèves de$3^{\textrm{ème}}$.
  \item Quel est le caractère.\\
  Le caractère est la note obtenue. 
  \item Donner un tableau des effectifs, des effectifs cumulés, des fréquences et des fréquences cumulées
  \begin{center}
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
    la note & \textcolor{blue}{6} & \textcolor{red}{7} & \textcolor{green}{8} & \textcolor{purple}{9} & \textcolor{violet}{10} & \textcolor{magenta}{12} & \textcolor{cyan}{13} & \textcolor{brown}{14} &  \textcolor{pink}{15} & \textcolor{orange}{16} \\\hline
     l'effectif & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 2 \\\hline
     l'effectif cumulé & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 27 & 31 & 36 & 38 & 40 \\\hline
     la fréquence & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ &$\scriptsize\dfrac{7}{40}=0.175$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{5}{40}=0.125$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{2}{40}=0.05$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{2}{40}=0.05$ \\\hline
     \multicolumn{11}{|c|}{On peut aussi trouver la fréquence cumulée }\\\hline
     la fréquence cumulées & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{8}{40}=0.2$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{12}{40}=0.3$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{16}{40}=0.4$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{20}{40}=0.5$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{27}{40}$ & $\dfrac{31}{40}=0.675$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{36}{40}=0.9$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{38}{40}=0.95$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{40}{40}=1$ \\\hline
   \end{tabular}
  \end{center}

\end{itemize}
 \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: this is my table that i want to resize]

Comment: I think you should swap rows and columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[top=1.5cm, bottom=3cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz,pgfplots}
 \usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\usepackage{tikz,tkz-tab}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz,lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,breakable,title= Statistiques ,attach boxed title to top center=
    {yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},boxed title style={size=small,colback=purple } ]
 \section*{I- Vocabulaires}
\section*{II- Tableaux des effectifs et des effectifs cumulés de fréquences et de fréquences cumulées}
 \subsection*{Exercice d'application: }
 Voici les notes obtenues à une évaluation en mathématiques des élèves de$3^{\textrm{ème}}$:
 \begin{eqnarray}\nonumber\textcolor{violet}{10}  ;; \textcolor{green}{8}  ;;  \textcolor{purple}{9}  ;;  \textcolor{pink}{15}  ;;  \textcolor{cyan}{13}  ;;  \textcolor{brown}{14}  ;;  \textcolor{magenta}{12}  ;; \textcolor{red}{7}  ;; \textcolor{blue}{6} ;;  \textcolor{brown}{14}  ;;  \textcolor{orange}{16}  ;; \textcolor{brown}{14}  ;;  \textcolor{magenta}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{violet}{10}  ;;  \textcolor{purple}{9}  ;; \textcolor{green}{8}  ;; \textcolor{red}{7}  ;;  \textcolor{blue}{6}  ;;  \textcolor{purple}{9}  ;;  \textcolor{cyan}{13}  \\\nonumber  \textcolor{green}{8}  ;;  \textcolor{red}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{orange}{16}  ;; \textcolor{magenta}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{magenta}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{violet}{10}  ;;  \textcolor{violet}{10}  ;;  \textcolor{red}{7}  ;;  \textcolor{magenta}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{blue}{6}  ;;  \textcolor{red}{7}  ;;  \textcolor{green}{8}  ;;  \textcolor{purple}{9}  ;;  \textcolor{red}{12}  ;;  \textcolor{cyan}{13}  ;;  \textcolor{pink}{15}  ;;  \textcolor{blue}{6} ;; \textcolor{cyan}{13}  ;;  \textcolor{brown}{14}  ;;  \textcolor{brown}{14}
\end{eqnarray}

\begin{itemize}
 \item Quelle est la population statistique\\la population statistique est les élèves de$3^{\textrm{ème}}$.
  \item Quel est le caractère.\\
  Le caractère est la note obtenue. 
  \item Donner un tableau des effectifs, des effectifs cumulés, des fréquences et des fréquences cumulées
  \begin{center}
    \resizebox{0.95\textwidth}{!}{%
   \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
    la note & \textcolor{blue}{6} & \textcolor{red}{7} & \textcolor{green}{8} & \textcolor{purple}{9} & \textcolor{violet}{10} & \textcolor{magenta}{12} & \textcolor{cyan}{13} & \textcolor{brown}{14} &  \textcolor{pink}{15} & \textcolor{orange}{16} \\\hline
     l'effectif & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 4 & 7 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 2 \\\hline
     l'effectif cumulé & 4 & 8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 27 & 31 & 36 & 38 & 40 \\\hline
     la fréquence & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ &$\scriptsize\dfrac{7}{40}=0.175$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{5}{40}=0.125$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{2}{40}=0.05$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{2}{40}=0.05$ \\\hline
     \multicolumn{11}{|c|}{On peut aussi trouver la fréquence cumulée }\\\hline
     la fréquence cumulées & $\scriptsize\dfrac{4}{40}=0.1$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{8}{40}=0.2$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{12}{40}=0.3$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{16}{40}=0.4$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{20}{40}=0.5$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{27}{40}$ & $\dfrac{31}{40}=0.675$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{36}{40}=0.9$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{38}{40}=0.95$ & $\scriptsize\dfrac{40}{40}=1$ \\\hline
   \end{tabular}}
  \end{center}

\end{itemize}
 \end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Resizebox will result in inconsistent font sizes. I would not recommend that.